# How to handle browser close, tab close and reload event

Tags: angular, browser, cross-browser, webbrowser-control

I have to show custom modal whenever the user tries to reload tab, close tab or close browser.

I have tried to handle onbeforeunload event but it not allowing me to show the custom message in chrome.

I am wondering even if it is possible to or not to handle in cross-browser application

**I have to show some modal with custom design and massage which also has ok and cancel button in particular case.** button action also have to handle accordingly

Please suggest is there any way to do that..
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this :

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class Component {
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event) {
    console.log('unloadHandler');
}

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there, Can u please guide me how to use our own dialog and handle both the events (OK/CANCEL).                                                                                                                                          Thanks in advance.